# Does using render_template() with Flask-SocketIO cause non-auto-updating?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I recently ported a Socket.IO app from Node.js to Python. I noticed that unlike the Node.js original, the Python version didn't autoupdate on multiple connections. While that app is far too complex to post on a simple SO question, here is a minimal reproduction of my issue.

Create a file called `templates/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <title>Test chat app - multiple connections</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script>
        let socket = io();

        document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", () => {
            let msg = document.getElementById("message").value;
            socket.emit("chat", {
                message: msg
            });
        })

        socket.on("update", (messages) => {
            document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = messages.map((message) => `<p>${message}</p>`).join("")
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Create a file called `test.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

messages = []

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connect():
    emit("update", messages)

@socketio.on("chat")
def handle_chat(data):
    msg = data["message"]
    messages.append(msg)
    emit("update", messages)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, port=5500)
```

Now run `python test.py`, and open 2 tabs at  http://localhost:5500. If you try sending messages on the first tab, they don't show up on the second tab.

I have a suspicion that this is due to how Flask serves static assets. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't just want to send your messages back to the sender, but distribute them to all connected clients.
In this case, the documentation mentions [broadcasting](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#broadcasting).

> When a message is sent with the broadcast option enabled, all clients connected to the namespace receive it, including the sender. When namespaces are not used, the clients connected to the global namespace receive the message.

```py
@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(data):
    emit('my response', data, broadcast=True)
```